# ExpandableListView group item disorder after expanding

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

**I have an ExpandableListView that works fine, with one exception.**

The ExpandableListView works like I load the group (with my dimensions texts) and child items (with my objects texts) and it handles them internally. If a child is selected I get called. But not in-between.

*I never update it, I do a this.recreate(); when data is changed, so the ExpandableListView always have the same data. I just load it once position by position (with my DimensionItems text) when being callbacked upon after creation, creating a textView and set a text on it.*

```
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_right_second, null);
            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
            text.setText(DimensionItems[groupPosition].title);
            if( Commands.AccountingObject.getObjectTotals(Commands.AccountingDimension.getDimensionByPositions(groupPosition))==0)
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

**The problem symptom**

If I select and get a group item expanded (put my finger on the group item, so I can see the children) the following group items are in disorder.

I have eight group items 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

And if I expand group 3 with two children I will have a list of 0, 1, 2, 3, c1, c2, 6, 7, 5, 4, real odd?

And there is no place in my code that interacts in the expansion phase, it all is internal in the ExpandableListView.Java that is outside my code, and the debugger refuse to put breakpoints in it. It is real hard to track, and there is no entry point from where I can put a breakpoint in my code, when not interfered.

Is there something I need to do about it or is it a bug in the ExpandableListView library?

Comment: if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_right_second, null);} find id  and set text after that

Comment: I will check it out, tomorrow. But the order is correct at start, also if I close the group (children goes away). But when I open the group (children are visual) the group item disorder appears. That is why it is so odd?

Answer (score 0):

**It was a re-write issue bug in a code-sample**

After some long learning about a lot about ExpandableListViews and nothing helped, it all ended up being as usual a simple horrible bug infront of my nose. There was a rewrite issue, some code inside the brackets should be outside (run every time). I am slightly embarrassed.

It should correctly look like this, no ids are needed, just positions.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_right_second, null);
    }
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
    text.setText(DimensionItems[groupPosition].title);
    if( Commands.AccountingObject.getObjectTotals(Commands.AccountingDimension.getDimensionByPositions(groupPosition))==0)
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    else
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: The counting ID issue is rather important to the  lastSelectedView solution for the children that do not work but is common among samples (because of re-writing).